# How to add a Date Picker in Power BI report builder

Tags: parameters, datepicker, powerbi, report, rdl

I need to create a From date and to date calendar prompts in Power BI report builder paginated reports.

Can anyone please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I searched everywhere for the answer, just to find out the solution is so stupid.

When you have Power BI Report Builder open, right-click Parameters, then click Add Parameter as can be seen below:

[image: Add Parameter]

Specify your Parameter Name, then change the Data Type to Date/Time as can be seen below:

[image: Adding Parameter]

**DO NOT** specify "Available Values", as this will cause your Date Picker not to show...

You can specify "Default Values" if need be.

Click OK.

Your Parameter will look like this:

[image: Parameter Created]

If you click on "Run", you will be able to click on the Date Picker as can be seen below:

[image: Date Picker]

I hope this helps, as it took me a while to get this to work!

Answer (score -2):

In the Power BI model, place two columns - From Date and To Date with Date datatype.
Add one Slicer for From Date and another slicer for To Date in the Power BI canvas.

Detailed steps can be found in [Link](https://radacad.com/from-and-to-date-slicers-in-power-bi-filtering-based-on-two-fields)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your update but I was asking for paginated reports. in paginated reports we need to select the data type as date and available values as none then calendar will be created.

Comment: I do not think this is possible yet and looking for a solution still. I did see this article and it looks like the date picker was used: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Date-Picker-in-Paginated-report/m-p/2293152

Comment: @DmitriK, it is possible, see my answer... :-)

Comment: Yes, I got it working.